# vim select {}/() plus the leading dollar

Tags: select, vim, block

If the cursor is inside a {} or () block, select the block plus the leading dollar. If not, do nothing.
Is there an easy way without having to write a function for that?

If have to do scripting, my question is how to check if any texts are currently selected.

BR,Ruochen

Comment: A point can be made that the Dollar _is_ leading the world, but I'm puzzling about what leading dollar you're referring to.

Comment: Could you provide some sample text and cursor positions? Otherwise it'll be pretty much impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to visually select the `${bar baz}` in the following sample:

```
lorem ipsum ${bar baz} sit amet.
```

**One method among *many***

```
vab
```

should select the whole `(foo bar)`.

```
vaB
```

should select the whole `{bar baz}`.

From there, you can move the cursor to the other end of the visual selection and expend it to include that elusive leading `$` with:

```
oh
```

In one go:

```
viboh
viBoh
```

**Another method**

```
F$vf)
F$vf}
```

should move the cursor to the first `$` to the left and start selection from there to the next closing parenthesis to the right. Of course, you can do it the other way if it makes more sense for you:

```
f)vF$
f}vF$
```

**Mapping it**

If, somehow, you find those *sentences* too complicated, you can create custom mappings:

```
nnoremap <key> f)vF$
nnoremap <key> f}vF$
```

**Creating a custom text-object**

The downside to this is that you will need additional mappings for other modes and other operators. Unless you create a custom text-object:

```
xnoremap a$ /[})]<CR>o?$<CR>
onoremap a$ :<C-u>normal va$<CR>
```

which lets you do `va$`, of course, but also `ca$`, `da$`, `ya$`, etc. on either `$(foo bar)` or `${bar baz}`.

Comment: Your solution kind of works but not entirely correct. Considering a line such as $(if $(findstring a,$(b)),...), f)vF$ will select $(b) rather than the whole $(if ...) block if the cursor is currently at the work if.  I adjust the key map to v])F$ but still one question remaining - if the cursor is just at the very ending ), nothing is selected.

Comment: My solution covers the most simple case I could think of given the lack of samples and proper description of the desired behavior. I'd say you got a lot more than your question deserved. If you want a more universal and perfect solution, take a look at `:help searchpairpos()`.